# jquery single button for animation

Tags: jquery

Needing help here with an jquery animation for my project website. Rather new to jquery here so any help is great. Is their a way to create a single button for this animiation i have sliding in from the left side of the page? I currently have it working but with two buttons, wanting only one. Any ideas are appreciated

```
jquery:
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div23 p").hide();
  $("#OpenButton").click(function(){
       $("#div23 p").show();
    var div=$("#div23");  
    div.animate({left:'200px'},"slow");
    div.animate({fontSize:'3em'},"slow");
  });
     $("#CloseButton").click(function(){
         var div=$("#div23"); 
         div.animate({left:'-200px'},"slow");
         div.animate({fontSize:'1em'},"slow");
         $("#div23 p").hide();
     });
});
</script> 


html:
<button id="OpenButton">Start Animation</button>
<button id="CloseButton">Close</button>
</div>
<p></p>
<div id="div23" style="background:transparent;height:5%;width:10%;position:absolute;"><p></p></div>


css:
#div23
{
background:transparent;
height:5%;
width:150%;
position:relative;
left:-100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var opened = false;
    $("#div23 p").hide();

    $("#onlyButton").click(function(){
        if(!opened){
            opened = true;
            $("#onlyButton").html("Close");

            $("#div23 p").show();

            var div=$("#div23");  
            div.animate({left:'200px'},"slow");
            div.animate({fontSize:'3em'},"slow");
        }else{
            opened = false;
            $("#onlyButton").html("Open");

             $("#div23 p").hide();

            var div=$("#div23"); 
            div.animate({left:'-200px'},"slow");
            div.animate({fontSize:'1em'},"slow");           
        }
    });
});
```

You can have just one button and one event handler, but they do different things based on the current state of the div. Here's a link to the JS Fiddle running the code (I changed the div's background color to red just so it'll show up here): [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osph92tz/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch this works perfectly, both solutions provided have

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to keep track of the clicks by counting the clicks. If the count is a even number, do the animation else reverse the animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div23 p").hide();
    var c = 0;
    $("#OpenButton").click(function () {
        if (c % 2 == 0) {
            $("#div23 p").show();
            var div = $("#div23");
            div.animate({
                left: '0px'
            }, "slow");
            div.animate({
                fontSize: '1em'
            }, "slow");
        } else {
            var div = $("#div23");
            div.animate({
                left: '-110px'
            }, "slow");
            div.animate({
                fontSize: '1em'
            }, "slow");
            $("#div23 p").hide();
        }
        c++;
    });
});
```

```css
#div23 {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    width: 100px;
    position:relative;
    left:-110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="OpenButton">Start Animation</button>
<p></p>
<div id="div23">
    <p></p>
</div>
```